# Creating network using QNetwork?

Tags: qgis, error, network

I have a point shapefile (Houses.shp) and various lines shapefiles (SemiRadial.shp, MST.shp, Ring.shp, etc) representing respectively houses of a village and possible microgrid network layout connecting those houses together. I would like to create networks using QNetwork plug-in to analyze different characteristics of each network, such as average shortest path between nodes.

As far as I understood, to create a network with QNetwork you need at least one node layer, which would be my house shapefile, and one polyline layer, which would be any of my lines shapefiles. The problem is that during the creation of the network QGIS crashes (tried that several times, with different polyline layers and also with new point/polyline layers created on purpose to see if my existing layers were the problem).

I noticed that even with the crash, the network directory "my_network" was indeed created, but it's not possible to load it in the project using QNetwork --> Load Network because it does not read it. Does anybody have experience using QNetwork and could maybe give me some hints on what I am doing wrong?

I attach images of the various steps of the process in case I am doing some basic silly mistakes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]